# Simple Mail Delivery Protocol (SMDP), where is it today? what do you think of it?

Tags: email, spam, smtp

So I'm doing a research study on Simple Mail Delivery Protocol (SMDP)
for those of you who don't know what it is, it's a new protocol for Email delivery that promises complete anti-spam filtering.

While I was doing my research I only found [one academic paper](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01470550/document) made by the students who actually proposed the new protocol (It's not really new the paper was published back in 2013), and that's it one paper in the entire world wide web!

Does any of you actually know what happened to that protocol? is it dismissed for good?

Answer (score 1):

From the paper:

> ... we presented the principle of operation for our protocol. For the future we plan to develop the software to implement SMDP and operate and evaluate a
>   pilot based on our design

Looks like none of this happened - or at least nothing can be found on the internet which suggests that nothing more than this purely conceptional paper was done. The authors likely moved on to other things. But when in doubt just contact the original authors.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I have contacted them, I'll update the question whenever they write back